# Error getting touch coordinates in android studio

Tags: java, android

This is the code:

```
private static Point c;
//c.set(1,1); -> error: "cannot resolve symbol set"??
.
.
.

    @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
            switch (event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    c.set((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY());
            }
            return true;
        }
```

When I touch anywhere on the screen the app crashes and I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.Point.set(int, int)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Where did you initialise c ?

Comment: How do I initialize a point?

Comment: Use `c = new Point();` before `c.set((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY());` or 
 just `new Point((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY())` and maybe you should store the `Point`'s in a `List<Point>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Point c` is null because you haven't initialized it. And to initialize it you should write

```
c = new Point(); // before setting coordinates to c
```

which makes a new object of the class `Point`.